# Using Swift to Expand SkSpriteNode while pan gesture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hope you are fine.

I have trouble with the following:

Currently I try to expand the background of my app while using the pan gesture. To be more specific, the user should be able to “pan” to the right/left and the app “smoothly” displays the expanded or new background.

To visualise it look at the following example gif, please:

[image: example]

The background is a *SKSpriteNode* and I thought it is possible by using *cameraNode* or *anchorPoint*. But I don’t get it to work. After finding myself on Google page 23 I started to get desperate. Probably I’m using the wrong terms for the search.

I’m only able to show a new scene or the full “new” background. And that’s not what I want.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Make a wrapper class around UIScrollView.

Comment: Thanks, gonna check that and give you feedback!

Comment: do you have any code snippets or links to share with me? I can't get this working.

Comment: I don't understand the question, you can rephrase and add a bit of code with the problem?